# How to find "file-release" in os x el capitan 10.11.6?

Tags: filesystem

I can not find file-release through command line on os x el capitan Version 10.11.6. On my virtual machine in Ubuntu I can do "ls /etc/*release" and it shows me two files with all needed information. No idea how to find the file with release information on mac. Please give me a hint or a hint how to search it?

Comment: This is a site for elementary OS. For macOS, see askdifferent.com